# Youtube video not playing in portrait mode

Tags: android, video, youtube, landscape, portrait

I have used Youtube api in my android code ,when i play the video in portrait mode it gets paused after a second but when i play it in full screen(landscape) mode it works fine. Here is some relevant code:

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
```

@Override

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    //** Start buffering **//*
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("video ID");
    }

    player.getDurationMillis();
}

private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

};

private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {

    }
};
```

}